# Can't proceed in tutorial: How do I switch to independent realms map mode?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I've started the tutorial, but I haven't proceeded very far.... How do I switch to independent realms map mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That part of the tutorial seems to be currently broken.

In a recent version (v1.09), selecting map modes changed. What you're supposed to do is to click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button:

[image: The plus button highlighted]

Which will show the various map modes that you can use (independent realms is the second button with the image of a shield):

[image: Map modes highlighted]

But doing this doesn't work in the tutorial right now. I think you'll have to skip the rest of this tutorial and continue with other tutorials. (There is a <kbd>▶</kbd> button for that in the lower left corner.)

[This bug has already been reported by other players.](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?662908-Linux-Can-t-Play-Tutorials-That-Require-Map-Mode-Change)